# How to set up factory in FactoryBot with has_and_belong_to_many association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, factory-bot

I have the following models that have **has_and_belong_to_many** associations:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
    ...
    has_and_belongs_to_many :user_roles {join_table :users_user_roles, class_name: 'Role' }
    ...
end
    
class Role < ApplicationRecord
    ...
    has_and_belongs_to_many :users {join_table :users_user_roles, class_name: 'User' }
    ...
end
```

**Factory(:user)**

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :users do
    # attributes
    association :user_roles, :factory => :user_role
  end
```

end

The **:user_role** are similarly setup.

This does not work. When I run the tests I get an `undefined method 'each'` error

Comment: 1. [You don't actually want to use HABTM](https://flatironschool.com/blog/why-you-dont-need-has-and-belongs-to-many/). It will bar you from adding features like soft-delete and "whodunnits" or recording when a user was granted a role 2. You don't need to configure the hell out of everything. And what is this wierd block configuration in your model? 3. This isn't actually answerable without a complete example where you show the code that actually leads to the error. You're just assuming that your assocation is the problem. Which is most likely wrong.

Comment: This is in the documentation. https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_bot/blob/master/GETTING_STARTED.md#has_and_belongs_to_many-associations